# Convertir Base64 a Imagen usando Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans-8.0

espero me puedan apoyar un favor con este problema, tengo una variable String que contiene la imagen codificado en Base64 y lo que quiero es que al darle click en la imagen en otra pagina me aparezca la imagen completa, este es mi código dentro del Servlet.

```
response.setContentType("image/png"); 

String Archivo_Base64 = request.getParameter("Archivo_B64");
byte[] Archivo_datos = Base64.getDecoder().decode(Archivo_Base64);
InputStream LecturaByte_Archivo = new ByteArrayInputStream(Archivo_datos);

int Total_BytesArchivo = LecturaByte_Archivo.available();
byte[] Datos_Imagen = new byte[Total_BytesArchivo];
LecturaByte_Archivo.read(Datos_Imagen, 0, Total_BytesArchivo);

response.getOutputStream().write(Datos_Imagen);
LecturaByte_Archivo.close();
```

Noto que no tengo ningún error en el código, pero al darle click en la imagen, me sale una pagina diciendo: "Esta página no funciona", pero si muestra en la url la direccion del servlet y la variable que se envia. No se cual es mi error, un favor ayundenme no se en que estoy fallando.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esta etiqueta envío el parámetro que contiene la imagen en String Base64.

```
<a href="Servlet_Mostrar_Archivo?Archivo_B64=<%=Archivo_Base64 %>" target="_blank"><image title="Imagen" /></a>
```

Cualquier ayuda será bienvenida, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas hacer el proceso de decodificación, ya que el navegador es capaz de hacerlo.
Es más, si lo hace el navegador en vez de hacerlo tú en tu servidor te ahorrarás hacer el procesamiento y lo delegarás al cliente reduciendo posiblemente en gastos de procesamiento y mejorando el uso de la memoria.

Simplemente debes de agregar en tu HTML un elemento `img` con valor en `src` de una URL de la siguiente manera:

```
<img src="data:[MIME TYPE];base64, [CONTENIDO EN BASE 64]" />
```

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

Ahora, suponiendo que te equivoques en el mime de tu contenido, los bytes del arcivo descargado seguirán indicando el tipo original, así que lo más probable es que de todas formas se pueda abrir.

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

```html
<img src="data:image/bmp;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

En tu caso creo que sería muy fácil modificar tu código a

```
<img src="data:<%= Tipo_Mime %>;base64, <%=Archivo_Base64 %>" />
```

para hacer que se muestren.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón Ruslan llego a mostrar todas las imagenes a través de un ArrayList en una tabla pero yo en la misma tabla manejo información por lo que se llega a ver muy desordenado y por esa razón solo quiero que me muestren los links de cada imagen y cuando de click en cualquieras de los link, entonces que me muestre la imagen completa en una pagina jsp aparte.